# Schur-concave functions, derivative sign help

Tags: inequality

To establish some inequality I must prove: $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon}\left[\dfrac{h(x,y+\varepsilon)}{x+y+\varepsilon}+\dfrac{h(w-\varepsilon,z)}{w+z-\varepsilon}\right]_{\varepsilon=0}\ge 0 \tag{1}$$
where $h$ is a Schur-concave function that is homogeneous of degree zero, and moreover: $x>y,w,z$ **and** $z<x,y,w$.

It is easy to prove  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon}\left[h(x,y+\varepsilon)+h(w-\varepsilon,z)\right]_{\varepsilon=0}\ge 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \varepsilon}\left[\frac 1{x+y+\varepsilon}+\frac 1{w+z-\varepsilon}\right]_{\varepsilon=0}\ge 0$, this last inequality provided $x+y\ge w+z$. **If we assume  $\mathbf{x+y\ge w+z}$ can we prove (1)?** If this is not the case, any suggestions or hints on how to approach this problem?

*Meta: I was not sure which tags to use, tag suggestions welcome as well*